# React Native - Android BackHandler - How to implement this.OnMainScreen and this.goBack

Tags: android, react-native, back-button, navigator

I have splash screen on my apps, so I want to exit the apps when we click android back button from the main page (not go back to splash screen). So I want to implement this method from react-native tutorial.

```
if (!this.onMainScreen()) {
    this.goBack();
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Is there anyone can help me how to implement onMainScreen(), and goBack() functions?
Thank you for the help.

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to use this function

```
function getCurrentRouteFromState(navigationState): NavigationRouteConfigMap {
  const route = navigationState.routes[navigationState.index];
  // dive into nested navigators
  if (route.routes) {
    return getCurrentRouteFromState(route);
  }
  return route;
}
```

pass it your navigation state and access the `routeName` member on the resulting object:

`let screenName = getCurrentRouteFromState(state).routeName` then you can compare the screen name with your main screen name and decide what to do.

Comment: In my case it looks like
`const currentRouteName = router.getPathAndParamsForState(state).path.split('/').reverse()[0]`

Answer (score 0):

So, On your main page(I think which is your Main.js)

```
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';    
componentWillMount(){
BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', function() {
  BackHandler.exitApp();
});
}
```

Comment: With this approach, on every back  `BackHandler.exitApp();` runs

Comment: @AmirShabani Yup sadly, Any solution?

Comment: @AmirShabani Yup sadly, Any solution?

Comment: @DevAS I guess, remove the handler when you navigate to another page and assign the handler again when you visit this page.